# How does 「信じられている」 differ from 「信じている」 in this sentence?

Tags: translation, potential-form, literature, passive-form

> 仲睦まじい様子の男女二人連れと、幾度もすれちがう。この中で、どれほどの人たちが、いま一緒にいる相手のことを、**この人しかいないと信じられているのだろうか。**

This is a line from 「私の男」by 桜庭一樹著

When I searched for the translation online, I found this one
[image]

> I wondered how many of them believed that the person next to them right now was the only one. Each person passing by might have his or her own circumstances.

[Source](https://www.proz.com/translator/1126210?text=English%20to%20Japanese%2C%20Japanese%20to%20English%20translator%20specialized%20in%20computer%20technology%20and%20general%20topics)

It does not seem to differentiate between 信じられている and 信じている. What is the difference between この人しかいないと信じられているのだろうか and この人しかいないと信じているのだろうか and what nuance does former have over latter?

Comment: Can you identify the usage/meaning of られる here?  That translation will not help you do that.

Comment: @l'électeur, I know it is not passive because of `どれほどの人たちが` but I just can't wrap my head around 信じられている

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the teiru-form of 信じられる, which has a potential meaning here ("to be able to believe"). So the difference between 信じている and 信じられている is basically the same as that between 歩いている ("is walking") and 歩けている ("can be walking"). Thus the literal translation is "I wonder how many of them can be believing ...", but the translator may have thought this sounded redundant as an English sentence.

Comment: From an English point of view, both would be almost equivalent in this situation. There's three possibilities here: 1. They're interchangeable in this context, in that case we just need your confirmation with a small explanation on the subtle nuance (easiest case for us to understand) 2. They have a different meaning, a concept that we simply cannot understand, this would need explaining also on the meaning in this context. 3. The form without potential doesn't work in that context. Which one is it?

Comment: ^This is what I wanted to ask. I think you put it better. Thanks @Simon.

Comment: I think passive form is difficult because of `どれほどの人たちが〜信じられている` instead of `どれほどの人たちに〜信じられている` (much easier to understand).

Comment: @vadasambar There is no passive meaning at all. I think saying "they *can* believe" (instead of "they believe") implies they are believing something that's normally difficult to believe.

Comment: Thanks naruto. I will accept this answer. For anyone reading this, it means (1) of what @Simon wrote seems to be the right answer i.e., there is little difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

One important thing to note here is that this potential form doesn't translate to "can" or "being able to" in English. The general meaning taken in this context is a conditional: "I wonder ***if*** they believed that [...]". This usage is reflected in English with the use of "would" and "could". This distinction is not present in Japanese. A representative translation of both would be:

- "I wonder how many of them were believing that [...]"
- "I wonder how many of them ***could*** have been believing that [...]"

Both of these sentences mean almost exactly the same thing, but as @naruto suggested, the second sentence might indeed put more emphasis on the fact that the situation is hard to believe. I suppose the nuance is the same in Japanese.

The second one might seem a little redundant in English, because the sentence starts with "I wonder", implying at the same time that you're questioning whether they believe something or not. This information already tells us that the situation is hard to believe in some sense. I'm guessing that, since that information is at the end in the Japanese sentence (のだろうか), it might feel more natural to mention it before.

Another thing to note is that the progressive tense of "believe" is generally not used in English to the point where I'm wondering if the two sentences I wrote are correct. The reason is that "believing" is thought to be something more general, a *belief*. To believe "continuously" is something that doesn't need to be precised in English. This is why we prefer using something like "I wonder how many of them believed [...]". To talk about something happening right now, "thinking" is generally preferred in that situation.

Comment: This clears up so much. Thanks a lot! Wish I could accept 2 answers.